# which of this functions are faster and better?

Tags: php

for remote a file from a server to another server which of this functions is better and faster ?

[FSOCKOPEN](http://php.net/fsockopen) | [Copy](http://php.net/copy) | [FOPEN](http://php.net/fopen) | [FILE_GET_CONTENTS](http://php.net/file_get_contents) | [cURL](http://php.net/curl)

Thanks is advanced

Comment: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx

Comment: I prefer CURL for security reasons.

Comment: It's Mean fopen is faster and better ?

Comment: @Book Of Zeus: For me important is speed of transfer, whis of this is your suggestion ?

Comment: @Davood Simply read through the link I posted.

Comment: Well actually non of them will work if you want with a PHP script hosted on server A to copy file, hosted on server B (and file is not accessible via http) to server C... in other words, for server-to-server transfer, via scp for example, none of those will work anyway, and I really can't say which one will not work fastest, maybe it depends on timeout settings...

Comment: Curl is fast, I recommend to read what @mcb wrote.

Comment: @Book Of Zeus Is there an objective reason why you think curl is more secure than php's HTTP wrappers? So far, curl has had five ([1](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/adv_20101013.html)[2](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/adv_20100209.html)[3](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/adv_20090303.html)[4](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/adv_20070710.html)[5](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/adv_20051207.html)) vulnerabilities, whereas I can't find a single one of php's HTTP stream wrapper. Note that curl's 5 vulnerabilities in still make an excellent track record for 10 years of software development.

Comment: That article was written 6 years ago. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Book Of Zeus huh, to which article are you referring to? Was that to be supposed @ me?

Comment: this one: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/adv_20100209.html #5 on the list. If you don't like curl you can use other others one. Also, all these vulnerabilities are fixed right after version 7.21.2 right?

Comment: @Book Of Zeus Please prepend your comments with `@phihag` so that I get notified of them. The oldest advisory I listed is indeed five years old. However, that's completely missing my point; that a good indication of a project's security is its history of vulnerabilities, and that curl fares **worse** than php's HTTP stream wrapper in that regard. Despite this fact, you said you'd prefer CURL for *security reasons*. Again, is there an objective reason why you think curl is more secure than php's HTTP wrappers?

Comment: Because with CURL you don't need to allow_url_fopen which I think is a bad practice *but that's just me talking here) since it allows hackers to import remote php scripts. http://www.buginteractive.com/blog/php-security-allow_url_fopen/

Comment: @Book of Zeus Why don't you notify me? Do you want me to appear unresponsive to comments or what? **Please start any comments with `@phihag` when you're responding to me.** Now, back to topic: Remote File Inclusion may still be possible when `allow_url_fopen` is set to off, especially if the web application in question allows users to upload any kind of data that is stored in the filesystem. So in effect, disabling `allow_url_fopen` is a way to treat symptoms and some aspects of a vulnerability, not the cause. That's precisely why magic quotes failed, so I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Profiled right now . `fread` and  `readfile` 0.1% CPU, `cURL` 0.2% CPU.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using these functions to transfer data from/to other hosts, the local speed doesn't matter, it will be dwarfed by the time it takes to transfer the data.

Use each function for what it's good for. In php, you can choose between using [stream wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) with most file functions or specialized functions.

Generic file functions that can be used with protocol wrappers:

- [`copy`](http://php.net/copy) - Well, copy a file.
- [`rename`](http://php.net/rename) - Move/rename a file.
- [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) - Read a file.
- [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) - Write a file.
- [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen) - fine grained reading, for example synchronized or read and write IO.

Specialized functions:

- [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) - HTTP requests that go beyond simply reading or writing a file, for example ranged requests. curl may also offer superior performance for HTTP communications because the current implementation of php's http stream wrapper does not support transparent gzip encoding. curl does, and that may speed up downloads of textual data at the expense of CPU overhead.
- [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/fsockopen) - Open a *socket*, i.e. direct network communication (not HTTP).

The above functions are ordered from specific to generic. Pick the first one in the list that matches your desired operation.

Comment: -1 because it says nothing about performance, easy-of-use and security aspects.

Comment: @mcb Performance will be about the same for all network functions. Trying to emulate, say, copy, with `fopen`, will be (slightly) slower, but that doesn't matter as long as you select the appropriate function for the appropriate job. ease-of-use is a similar topic: If you want to download a file from an HTTP server, you should not use `fsockopen` and emulate your own HTTP library, but use `file_get_contents`(or curl) instead. There is no difference in "security" - the term "security" is meaningless when applied to generic tools from one source. **Pick the right tool for the right job**.

Comment: @phihag last time I checked `file_get_contents` was somewhat CPU-hungry, especially for slow hosts

Comment: @sanmai That's anecdotal evidence at best. `file_get_contents` will be  faster than multiple `fopen`/`fread` calls unless php is buggy - it can be micro-optimized for just reading a file instead of providing the huge possibilities `fopen`&Co have to. If `file_get_contents` *is* indeed CPU-hungrier than `fopen`+`fread`, the proper course is to file a php bug (and maybe ask a *specific* stackoverflow question) instead of working around platform bugs.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to download something from somewhere and you have cURL on your server, stick to it. All the options are equally fast, but cURL is somewhat better on CPU and has nice additional features like support for compression and keep-alive. It'll will give you best results with peace of mind and minimal fuss.

If you don't have cURL, well, use built-in functions.